# Text Processing, How to assign 1 topic -> 1 document using LDA?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, topic-modeling, text-classification, gensim

I have 2 files,

**music.txt** & **science.txt**

I'd lke to extract 2 topics from the above (**Music** , **Science**)

After creating the LDA model from these 2 files (setting num_topics=**2**)

```
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=my_corpus, id2word=corpus_dictionary, num_topics=2)

print(lda.print_topic(0))
print(lda.print_topic(1))
```

This is my output

```
0.011*scientific + 0.010*musical + 0.007*music, + 0.006*music. + 0.006*study + 0.005*not + 0.005*research + 0.005*main

0.030*music + 0.013*science + 0.010*scientific + 0.009*musical + 0.006*not + 0.005*music. + 0.005*study + 0.005*music, + 0.005*their + 0.005*research
```

As you can see, **both** science and music are present in each of the 2 topics

I'd like to

1. Use music.txt and create 1 topic **Music** LDA model
2. Use science.txt and create 1 topic **Science** LDA model
3. Combine the above 2 LDA models to give 1 LDA model with the above 2 topics

is the above **3rd** step possible?  I'd like to have individual segregration of topics in my LDA model. If not, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do:

1) If your documents really contain texts that are exclusively about music or science, it is strange that the LDA topics give such a mixed result. Trying to improve the model may be worthwhile. You may consider dropping stopwords, ignoring low-frequency words, and so on.

2) However, the method that you're really looking for is so-called *labeled LDA*. With Labeled LDA, you train your model on documents *that have already been labeled with the target topics*, rather than having the model infer the most appropriate topics itself. As far as I know, labeled LDA has not been implemented in gensim, but you'll find it in the [Stanford Topic Modeling Toolkit](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/), among other places.